# Is there a minimal-boilerplate way I can send a GET request to my AWS endpoint?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rest, opensearch

So, I have some documents in OpenSearch that I need to query a lot. My requirement is nothing more than sending a GET request to search for a keyword in an index that I would also specify and get back a JSON document/string that I could process. The JSON documents could be of any length or format so, mapping it to a class is not a possibility.

I neither need to create indexes nor update or delete or anything else really. I only need the output of a GET request. I have the AWS endpoint, the username, and password for the endpoint with me and nothing else. Certificates, temporary access_keys and everything else is practically out of the question because my University won't give me anything more than this.

I prefer Java and was planning to deploy my code as a microservice using Elastic Beanstalk or some other method. I'm using Javalin to create my microservice's endpoints. Can't use SpringBoot, it's too heavy for my small use cases.

This is the code that I could get working out of all my tries.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder;
import org.opensearch.client.RestClient;
import org.opensearch.client.RestClientBuilder;
import org.opensearch.client.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpMapper;
import org.opensearch.client.opensearch.OpenSearchClient;
import org.opensearch.client.transport.OpenSearchTransport;
import org.opensearch.client.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport;

public class OpenSearchInstance {
    
    public OpenSearchClient createOpenSearchClient(String username, String password, String host, Integer port) {
        final HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost("https", port, host);
        final BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(httpHost), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        
        final RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(httpHost)
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback() {
                    
                    @Override
                    public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                        return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                    }
                }).build();
        
        final OpenSearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
        final OpenSearchClient client = new OpenSearchClient(transport);
        
        return client;
    }
}
```

But when I try to run this code from my Main class, I get a Host scheme not supported exception. For reference, the OpenSearch version of my endpoint is 2.7.0

My only use case is putting out GET requests with queries in them to OpenSearch and getting back the JSON string. I don't need any advanced functionality like pagination or sorting or anything really right now.